# Removing fill from google-maps KmlLayers

Tags: google-maps

I notice this morning that KmlLayers that I use to identify the boundary of Bullitt County KY are now being filled in with a blue color. Example is at http://bullittcountyhistory.org/if/andersonx.html . Is there a way to turn off the fill? All I want is the county boundary in blue.

The kml file is located at http://bullittcountyhistory.org/places/bullittboundary.kml and fill is set to 0 and outline to 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_frm/thread/17afaa377a5abc25#

Star this issue:
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4187

Comment: This was a bug and is now fixed

Comment: This is not true anymore

Comment: What isn't true?  Is it broken again?  The link in the original question still works and shows it working correctly (for at least that sample)